# Compiling .go in Windows ... & Can python connect to Go?

Tags: python, windows, go

i know that go language does not support windows yet, now, how can i compile .go file is windows ?

and can python connect to go ?

like connecting c++ or java to python ... lol

Comment: How about use a VM to run Linux with VirtualBox from Windows?

Comment: One question at a time, please!

Answer (score 4):

While the Go language implementation for Windows is still experimental, it's steadily improving. An updated binary version is published regularly: [Win32 build of Go](http://code.google.com/p/gomingw/downloads/list).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I never knew such a thing existed!